# Hosting laravel 5 app on shared hosting: getting js error "tinymce is not defined"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I know hosting laravel 5 app on shared hosting can be tricky but it's not impossible.

So I followed this tutorial's instructions
https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e

I moved the app files into a directory called `/reddit/` outisde `/public_html/` and the files inside the app's `/public/` folder into the hosting's `/public_html/`

Then I made changed to `index.php` in the `/public_html/` to point to the correct path

```
ini_set('eaccelerator.enable', 0);
require __DIR__.'/../reddit/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../reddit/bootstrap/app.php';
```

The app loads fine, but when I try to submit a new subreddit/category which requires the tinymce editor, it doesn't load and I get this error in the console

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token / create:203 Uncaught
>
> ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined

I am positive the html markup is pointing to the correct `tinymce.min.js` because if I view source, and click on the js link, the script loads in the browser.

My app is here: http://maghnatis.com

If you wanna see what's going on.

This is how I'm initializing it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        tinymce.init({
            selector : "textarea",
            menubar    : false,
            plugins : ["advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor", "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen", "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"],
            toolbar : "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        });
    });

<p>
    {!! Form::label('description', 'Description:') !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</p>
```

I'm afraid this isn't a problem with tinymce but rather how my app is loading the js files on the shared hosting. I believe I will get into my js errors with other libraries if I don't fix this.

I might add that `typeahead.js` is not working either. Doesn't retrieve records from the database even though the json response is positive.

http://maghnatis.com/data/subreddits

This is the JS code to typeahead.js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var subreddits = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            prefetch: 'data/subreddits',
            remote: {
                url: 'data/subreddits/%QUERY',
                wildcard: '%QUERY'
            }
        });

        $('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
            name: 'name',
            display: 'name',
            source: subreddits
        });

        $('#remote .typeahead').bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
            $('.subreddit_id').val(suggestion.id);
        });
    });

<div id="remote">
    <input class="form-control typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Choose a Subreddit" name="subreddit_name">
    <input type="hidden" class="subreddit_id" value="" name="subreddit_id">
</div>
```

Comment: what file and what line number is causeing the Unexpected token error?

Comment: it's in `tinymce.min.js` line 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already posted this on Laracasts, but I took a look at your site. TinyMCE is working fine on my end, but your path is wrong for typeahead, which is why you're getting that problem. This is what you have right now.

```
var subreddits = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: 'data/subreddits',
    remote: {
        url: 'data/subreddits/%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
});
```

`'data/subreddits',` should be `'/data/subreddits'` for it to be relative to the root. Otherwise, it'll be relative to the current URL.

Comment: How come tinymce works at your end but not mine? No matter how hard I refresh, I still get the same error. Adding the slash to the data url didn't help either.

Comment: I opened the site with TOR and it seems like everything is working. However I am facing a new error, I posted it on laracast, would you mind having a look at it? basically it's omitting `"{$extension}"` from the image file name and does not save to images dir